# BackgroundWorker. Stop thread execution

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

Good afternoon!
Can you tell me how to stop the execution of a thread? The following code doesn't work:

```vb
  Private Sub Stop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Stop.Click
        If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then

            If BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation Then
                BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you testing [CancellationPending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancellationpending) in `DoWork`? It's up to you.

Comment: Don't nest `If` blocks like that when there is no code between them. Test both conditions with one `If` statement: `If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy AndAlso BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation Then`.

Answer (score 3):

That code does exactly what it is supposed to do, i.e. REQUEST a cancellation. It can't just stop working though, because it has no idea what work is being done. YOU are the one writing the code to do the work so YOU are the one who has to write the code to check whether a cancellation has been requested and to actually perform that cancellation. We have no idea what work you're doing so we have no idea where it is convenient to check whether a cancellation has been requested and what, if any, clean-up may be required in that case. Here's a basic example of what a cancellation might look like though:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Raise the DoWork event in a worker thread.
    Me.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
 
'This method is executed in a worker thread.
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                     ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim worker As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker = DirectCast(sender, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)
 
    For i As Integer = 1 To 100
        If worker.CancellationPending Then
            'The user has cancelled the background operation.
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        End If
 
        'Raise the ProgressChanged event in the UI thread.
        worker.ReportProgress(i, i & " iterations complete")
 
        'Perform some time-consuming operation here.
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
    Next i
End Sub
 
'This method is executed in the UI thread.
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                              ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Me.ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    Me.Label1.Text = TryCast(e.UserState, String)
End Sub
 
'This method is executed in the UI thread.
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                                 ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled Then
        'The background operation was cancelled.
        Me.Label1.Text = "Operation cancelled"
    Else
        'The background operation completed normally.
        Me.Label1.Text = "Operation complete"
    End If
End Sub
 
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
                          ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Only cancel the background opertion if there is a background operation in progress.
    If Me.BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy Then
        Me.BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
    End If
End Sub
```